# Xcode 5: Autosizing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have the following problem:

I have a universal app. I use a tab bar, a navigation controller and a table view. There is nothing wrong, everything runs as it should.This is in Xcode 4.

But now I open the app in Xcode 5, something goes wrong. The view that comes after the table view, all have a text view. However, all text views are different in length.

In Xcode 4 I have properly set the autosizing for iphone / ipad. In Xcode 5 I have all the same settings. But the problem is that the text view is displayed differently. For short texts view begins at the top of the text. But for long texts, the view starts somewhere in the middle of the text. So I have to go up first to the beginning of the text to read. Also on the ipad, the view is not using the full width of the ipad to display the text anymore.

I have tried all of the autosizing, but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check your constraints, you probably need to pin the height of the text views

[image]